# Implementing Iterative deepening depth-first search

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, iterative-deepening

I am using the following pseudocode from the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) to implement iterative deepening depth-first search for graphs

```
function IDDFS(root)
    for depth from 0 to ∞
        found ← DLS(root, depth)
        if found ≠ null
            return found

function DLS(node, depth)
    if depth = 0 and node is a goal
        return node
    if depth > 0
        foreach child of node
            found ← DLS(child, depth−1)
            if found ≠ null
                return found
    return null
```

Here is my code:

```
bool DLS(GrapheMat* graphe, Node* source, NomSom but, int limit) {
    bool found = false;
    printf("%s\n", (char*)source->etat);
    if (strcmp((char*)source->etat, (char*)but) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (limit > 0) {
        List* listSon = nodeSon(graphe, source);
        while(!listEpmty(listSon)) {
            Node* son = (Node*)popList(listSon);
            if (DLS(graphe, son, but, limit-1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool IDDLS (GrapheMat* graphe, NomSom goal, int limit) {
    bool found = false;
    node* source = createNode(graphe, graphe->nomS[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
        printf("/nLimit : %d\n", i);
        DLS(graphe, source, goal, i);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am using the following graph to test :

[image]

It's built from the following file:

```
A B C D E F G H I J ;
A : B (140) C (118) D (75) ;
B : A (140) E (99) F (151) G (80);
C : A (118) ;
D : A (75) F (71) ;
E : B (99) H (211) ;
F : D (71) B (151) ;
G : B (80) I (146) J (97) ;
H : E (211) J (101) ;
I : G (146) J (138) ;
J : G (97) H (101) I (138) ;
```

Calling `IDDLS(graphe, "J", 4)` outputs the following:

```
/nLimit : 0
A
```

That's all.

Calling `DLS(graphe, "A", "J", 4)` outputs the following (newlines removed):

```
ABABAEFGCADAFEBAEFGHEJ
```

From what I understand, the DLS function should actually follow the following path:

```
ABEGHCDEFGHIJ
```

Comment: @ikegami I just edited the post with the output and the children are ordered alphabetically

Comment: @ikegami sorry i edited the post again, hope it's enough info

Comment: Re "*my output is:

/nLimit : 0
A
that's all*", That's impossible unless the process is killed by a signal. Is that what happened? If so, what signal?

Answer (score 2):

`DLS(graphe, "A", "J", 4)` is taking the right path. `ABABAEFGCADAFEBAEFGHEJ` is correct.

```
4  3  2  1  0

A                  A
├─ B               B
│  ├─ A            A
│  │  ├─ B         B
│  │  │  ├─ A      A
│  │  │  ├─ E      E
│  │  │  ├─ F      F
│  │  │  └─ G      G
│  │  ├─ C         C
│  │  │  └─ A      A
│  │  └─ D         D
│  │     ├─ A      A
│  │     └─ F      F
│  ├─ E            E
│  │  ├─ B         B
│  │  │  ├─ A      A
│  │  │  ├─ E      E
│  │  │  ├─ F      F
│  │  │  └─ G      G
│  │  └─ H         H
│  │     ├─ E      E
│  │     └─ J      J
C  F
D  G
```

---

In `IDDLS`, replace

```
DLS(graphe, source, goal, i);
```

with

```
if (DLS(graphe, source, goal, i)) {
    return true;
}
```

There's no need to keep looking deeper once you've found the node.

---

The only way `IDDLS(graphe, "J", 4)` could output what you say it does is if the program was killed by a signal (e.g. from `SIGSEGV`)<sup>[1]</sup>. Verify this (by checking the process's exit code). If that's the case, there's a problem with the functions `DLS` calls, or there's a problem with how it calls them.

---

You have a memory leak. The `List` created by `nodeSon` is never freed.

---

Optimized to remove needless string comparisons:

```
bool DLS(GrapheMat* graphe, Node* source, NomSom but, int limit) {
    printf("%s\n", (char*)source->etat);

    if (limit) {
        List* listSon = nodeSon(graphe, source);
        while (!listEpmty(listSon)) {
            Node* son = (Node*)popList(listSon);
            if (DLS(graphe, son, but, limit-1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    } else {
        return strcmp((char*)source->etat, (char*)but) == 0;
    }
}

bool IDDLS(GrapheMat* graphe, NomSom goal, int limit) {
    node* source = createNode(graphe, graphe->nomS[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= limit; ++i) {
        printf("/nLimit : %d\n", i);
        if (DLS(graphe, source, goal, i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

1. Well, it's also possible one of the functions you call calls `exit`, performs a long jump, or does something similarly weird.